# Returning a generic array using Array.map (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, generics, typescript

I wrote a function that gets a string array and supposed to convert it to a T array:

```
interface Fooable {
    foo: string;
}

function simplifiedExample<T extends Fooable>(bars: string[]): T[] {
    return bars.map(bar => {
        return {
            foo: bar
        }
    })
}
```

But the word "bars" in the first line of the function is marked by a red line, says:

> TS2322: Type '{foo:string;}[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'. Type '{foo:string}' is not assignable to type 'T'.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to type assert the returned `Fooable` to type `T`:

```
function simplifiedExample<T extends Fooable>(bars: string[]): T[] {
    return bars.map(bar => {
        return {
            foo: bar
        } as T;
    })
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Fooable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20simplifiedExample%3CT%20extends%20Fooable%3E(bars%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20bars.map(bar%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20bar%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20as%20T%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0A%0A))

The reason is that `T` isn't `Fooable`, it just extends it but might have additional properties, for example:

```
interface Mooable extends Fooable {
    moo: string;
}

simplifiedExample<Mooable>(["a", "b", "c"]);
```

In this case `T` is `Mooable` but `{ foo: bar }` doesn't satisfy it, which is why you need to type cast.

Comment: Most examples I see of this use casting instead of `as`, e.g. `return <T>{ foo: bar};` rather than `return {foo: bar} as T;` Is there a difference? If so, is there a good reason to go with `as` rather than a cast? Or are they just two ways to do the same thing?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder From [Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions): "The two samples are equivalent. Using one over the other is mostly a choice of preference; however, when using TypeScript with JSX, only as-style assertions are allowed".

Comment: Thanks! I had kicked around, but couldn't find it. So the `as` syntax is more flexible (can be used whether you're using JSX or not), whereas casting syntax can't be used if you're using JSX.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right. And as I'm using `TSX` I'm already used to the `as` syntax so I just always use that